# Can Apple calendar (that comes with the iPod touch) re-order tasks?

Tags: ipod-touch, calendar

I would like to re-order my task lists in the Apple calendar that came with my iPod Touch.

Is there any way to do this besides setting times for each task?

I prefer to label most of my tasks as "all day", rather than setting times for each, 
...but would sure like to "drag and drop" to re-order them !
My priorities change throughout the day !

Is there any way to have the "drag and drop" capability in the Apple calendar on my iPod Touch?

If not, is there an app with this capability...an app that also has the features of this Apple calendar?
(Task list, day view with all day tasks AND time-frame tasks (automatically put in their proper places),  month view (with dots or tasks listed on each day)

Comment: By "task" do you mean "event"?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the app called "paperless".

It's as close to this as I've found, but it isn't perfect: you have to switch back and forth between the Paperless app and the apple calendar to look at tasks that are on certain days vs. tasks on my paperless re-orderable list.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Before my edit, this post had a great deal of unnecessary commentary. Please make answers that focus on directly answering the question that was asked. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.